# jQuery ajax data with file send not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data with file using jQuery ajax. But its not working:

```
<script>
    function uploadImage() {

        var form = document.getElementById("table").value + "-form";
        alert(form);

        var formData = new FormData($("#" + form));
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            cache: false, 
            contentType: false, 
            processData: false, 
            dataType: "json" 
        });
    }
</script>
```

I have edited the code added enctype and dataType but am still not getting any files to the specified folder which is dynamically created based on inputs.

Here is my php code:

```
$mode=$_POST['mode'];
$table=$_POST['table'];
$fetch=$_POST['fetch'];
$id=$_POST[$fetch];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$pimg=$_FILES['pimg']['name'];
$size=$_FILES['pimg']['size'];
$temp=$_FILES['pimg']['tmp_name'];
$city=$_POST['city'];

$file=strtotime("now").$pimg;

$locn="files/".$id."/".$table;
if (!file_exists($locn)) {    mkdir($locn, 0777, true); }
$path=$locn."/";
$upload=move_uploaded_file($temp,$path.$file);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("test",$con);
$sql="INSERT INTO `".$table."` (name,gender,pimg,city) VALUES ('$name','$gender','$file','$city');";
$query=mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Php code is working when data submitted through submit button.

Comment: Why isn't it working? What errors are you getting, if any?

Comment: Have you encrypted your form with  enctype="multipart/form-data" ?
Try this var formData = new FormData($("#" + form)[0]);

Comment: I have edited the code added enctype and dataType but am still not getting any files to the specified folder which is dynamically created based on inputs. I have edited my question with the code modified and also added the Php code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, since you are not providing all necessary information:

The constructor for `FormData` takes an HTML Form element, not a jQuery object, as it's argument:

```
var formData = new FormData($("#" + form)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function uploadImage() {

        var form = document.getElementById("table").value + "-form";
        alert(form);

        var formData = new FormData($("#" + form));
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data', // add
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    }
</script>
```

add enctype if you are sending file from ajax